# Selecting overlapping points on a plot

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices which are built as follows

```
x1=cbind(V1,V2,ID)  
X2=cbind(V1,V2,ID)  
X3=rbind(X1,X2)
```

ID takes only the values "red" and "blue"

when I plot X1 and X2 I have the following plot

[image]

I want to select the data points which are within 1 unit distance (euclidian distance) basically filtering only the red points which are overlapping or quasi-overlapping a blue point or vice versa.

Red overlapping red and blue overlapping blue is not interesting for me.

Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for this one to get the best answer; however, I think below script will serve the purpose:

```
library(spatstat)


# setting seeds
set.seed(222)

# two different point patterns
X <- runifpoint(15)
Y <- runifpoint(20)
plot(X, pch=19, main="")
plot(Y, col="red", pch=19, add=T)

#you can get both which and dist from nncross
#N.which <- nncross(X,Y, k=1:20, what="which")
#N.dist  <- nncross(X,Y, k=1:20, what="dist")

out <- subset(X, nncross(X,Y, k=1:20, what="dist") < 0.1) # you may change 0.1
plot(out, col="blue", pch=19, add=T)
```

[image]

For the above plot, black points represent `X` and red points represent `Y`. Blue are intersecting points which are within **0.1** unit distance. This distance can be further modified. For more detaild please see `spatstat` to compute distances between two different datasets using `nncross`.

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked flowlessly! I just had to convert my matrices to ppp object and from there everything was so intuitive!